# unix tee command not working as expected

Tags: shell, unix

While i'm using the following command in unix command prompt everything is working fine,log fiel is creating fine.

```
  ls -l|echo "[`date +%F-%H-%M-%S`] SUCCESS - FILES"|tee -a logger2.log
```

but using the same thing in side the shell script it is showing error

No such file or directory. 
I'm not getting what is the problem here!!

Comment: are you sure that's the command line you are using? `ls -l|echo "[date +%F-%H-%M-%S] SUCCESS - FILES"` will simply echo out `[date +%F-%H-%M-%S] SUCCESS - FILES` (whatever the output of "ls -l" was)

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  Because the code as posted seems confused.

Comment: @dulac Bad formatting ate the shell backticks. Ignoring the output of `ls` is still an open issue.

Comment: I want print this meesage into log file [`date +%F-%H-%M-%S`] SUCCESS - FILES

Comment: Yes, in command line it is working, The files has created with the message given in echo

Comment: @RAVITEJASATYAVADA: to avoid confusion here (and also in your scripts!) replace backticks with `$(....)` : `ls -l | echo "[$(date "+%F-%H-%M-%S")]" | tee -a logger2.log` . For your problem, the first reason it could not work would be that when using the script, you are not in the same directory by default, and in that directory you don't have an existing (and writable) "logger2.log", and it can't create one? [wild guess...]

Comment: And you can just drop the `ls -l |` as it's not used at all (and just consume CPU for nothing) : `echo "[$(date "+%F-%H-%M-%S")]" | tee -a logger2.log` or even `echo "[$(date "+%F-%H-%M-%S")]" >> logger2.log`

Comment: @A.H.: thanks for the info, it clarified that part ^^

Answer (score 0):

If I read between the lines: you want a list of files, followed by a date and a message?

try:

```
 { ls -l ; echo "[$(date "+%F-%H-%M-%S")] SUCCESS - FILES" ; } |tee -a logger2.log
```

That should give you in 'logger2.log' of the current directory the lines

```
 .................... file
 .................... file2
 (ie the list of all files and dirs in the current dir, EXCEPT those starting with a ".")
 [2013-12-26-..-..-..] SUCCESS - FILES
```

Please note that, if you put nothing in front of the script, it could be started by a different shell than the one you use when testing. It depends what/who does invoke the script : if it is a crontab, it will probably be interpreted by "sh" (or by "bash" in "sh-compatibility" mode)...

Please tell us what the above gives you as output, and how you start the script (by a user, on the prompt? or via a crontab [which one: /etc/crontab ? or a user's crontab? which user?], etc. And what error messages you see.